# Difference between \z and \Z and \a and \A in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Can you please tell me the difference between `\z` and `\Z` as well as `\a` and `\A` in Perl with a simple example ?

Comment: no, we can't, because you haven't explained how/where these character sequences are being used.

Comment: @user3597719 [RT*M](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: It seems that you have made no effort to resolve this question yourself. This is all very clearly laid out in [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) under ***Assertions***.

Answer (score 20):

`\z` only matches the very end of the string.

`\Z` also matches the very end of the string, but if the string ends with a newline, then `\Z` also matches immediately before the newline.

So, for example, these five are true:

```
'foo' =~ m/foo\z/
'foo' =~ m/foo\Z/
"foo\n" =~ m/foo\Z/
"foo\n" =~ m/foo\n\z/
"foo\n" =~ m/foo\n\Z/
```

whereas this one is false:

```
"foo\n" =~ m/foo\z/
```

They both differ from `$` in that they are not affected by the `/m` "multiline" flag, which allows `$` to match at the end of any line.

`\a` denotes the alert (bell) character; it doesn't have any additional special meaning in a regex.

`\A` matches only at the start of a string. Like `\z` and `\Z`, and unlike `^`, it's not affected by the `/m` "multiline" flag.

All of this is documented in `perlre`, the Perl regular expressions manual page: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html.

Answer (score 7):

- `\A` matches zero characters at position 0.
- `\z` matches zero characters at the end of the string.
- `\Z` matches zero characters at the end of the string and at a trailing line feed.

- `^` without `/m` is the same as `\A`.
- `^` with `/m` matches zero characters at position 0 and after a non-final line feed.
- `$` without `/m` is the same as `\Z`.
- `$` with `/m` matches zero characters at the end of the string and at a line feed.

- `\a` matches the BEL/BELL character.

  - It is equivalent to `\x07` on an ASCII-based machine.
  - It is equivalent to `\x2F` on an EBCDIC-based machine.

The following indicates the positions at which the relevant regex patterns will match (`␊` indicates a line feed):

```
\A                       \A is not affected by /m
^-m                      ^ without /m             ≡ \A
^+m ^+m ^+m              ^ with /m                ≡ \A|(?<=\n(?!\z))
|   |   |
0123456789012
|   |   |
v   v   v
abc␊def␊ghi␊
   ^   ^   ^^
   |   |   ||
0123456789012
   |   |   ||___
   |   |   |    |
   $+m $+m $+m  $+m      $ with /m                ≡ \z|(?=\n)
           $-m  $-m      $ without /m             ≡ \z|(?=\n\z)
           \Z   \Z       \Z is not affected by /m ≡ \z|(?=\n\z)
                \z       \z is not affected by /m
```

This is documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).