# What does ($pre =~ /\./ && $pre =~ /\p{IsAlpha}/) mean in the Moses Tokenizer?

Tags: regex, perl, nlp, moses

[Moses Tokenizer](https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/tokenizer/tokenizer.perl#L333) is the tokenizer widely used in machine translation and natural language processing experiments.

There is a line of regex that checks for:

```
if (($pre =~ /\./ && $pre =~ /\p{IsAlpha}/) || 
   ($NONBREAKING_PREFIX{$pre} && $NONBREAKING_PREFIX{$pre}==1) || 
   ($i<scalar(@words)-1 && ($words[$i+1] =~ /^[\p{IsLower}]/)))
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong, the 2nd and 3rd conditions are to check

- whether the prefix is in a list of nonbreaking prefixes
- whether the word is not the last token and there is still a lowercased token as the next word.

The question is on the first condition where it checks for:

```
($pre =~ /\./ && $pre =~ /\p{IsAlpha}/)
```

1. Is the `$pre =~ /\./` checking whether the prefix is a single fullstop?
2. And is `$pre =~ /\p{IsAlpha}/` checking whether the prefix is an alpha from the list of alphabet in the [perluniprop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html)?
3. One related question is whether the fullstop is already inside the perluniprop alphabet? If so, wouldn't this condition never be true?

Comment: They check if those things are *contained*. No, FULL STOP is not an alphabetic letter.

Comment: Ah, now i see. So `$pre =~ /\p{IsAlpha}/` is checking whether all characters in `$pre` is in the peruniprop alphabet, right?

Comment: No, it checks if $pre *contains* a matching character, so it checks if *any* character in $pre matches.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami, that explains!

Comment: I misspoke when I said alphabetic *letter*. A number of characters are considered alphabetic (match `\p{IsAlpha}`) but aren't letters (match `\p{Letter}`) e.g. TAI VIET VOWEL AM

Comment: The `$str =~ /a/` returns true if there is (at least) one `a` anywhere in the string. So it's true for string `'alvas'` but not for `'hi'`. A _character class_ `/[a-z]/` matches any one lowercase letter, at least one. To match more than one thing you need a _quantifier_, like `/[a-z]+/` (matches a lowercase letter, one or more times in a row (need not be the same letter).  To test for a sole thing in a string use _anchors_, `/^a$/` (`'a'` only), for example. This is how _match operator_ works in the [_scalar context_](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context) (and there's more to it).

Comment: Actually, you'd need `/^a\z/` to test if the string being matched is exactly `a`.

Comment: Um, right, sorry. The `$` for a multiline string in a multiline mode (with `/m` [modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers)) isn't right.  This is covered in full detail in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526929/difference-between-z-and-z-and-a-and-a-in-perl), and documentation is [in perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) (scroll down to "_Assertions_")

Comment: I thought that the question was mostly answered in comments, but this is clearly not so. What do you need in an answer -- the same but written up and explained well?  Or is there more that the comments missed?

Comment: Yes yes, giving the bounty to @ikegami when he writes it up. So that the answer can be documented for posterity =)

Comment: OK, good cause, thank you for clarifying :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Please correct me if I'm wrong [about `$NONBREAKING_PREFIX{$pre} && $NONBREAKING_PREFIX{$pre}==1` checking] whether the prefix is in a list of nonbreaking prefixes*

Can't tell without knowing what `%NONBREAKING_PREFIX` contains, but it's a fair guess.

> *Please correct me if I'm wrong [about `$i<scalar(@words)-1 && ($words[$i+1] =~ /^[\p{IsLower}]/)` checking] whether the word is not the last token and there is still a lowercased token as the next word*

Assuming the code is iterating over `@words`, and `$i` is the index of the current word, then it checks if the current word is followed by a word that starts with a lowercase letter (as defined by Unicode).

> *Is the `$pre =~ /\./` checking whether the prefix is a single fullstop?*

Not quite. It checks if *any* of the characters in the string in `$pre` is a FULL STOP.

```
$ perl -e'CORE::say "abc.def" =~ /\./ ? "match" : "no match"'
match

$ perl -e'CORE::say "abc!def" =~ /\./ ? "match" : "no match"'
no match
```

Perl first tries to find a match at position 0, then at position 1, etc, until it finds a match.

> *And is $pre =~ /\p{IsAlpha}/ checking whether the prefix is an alpha from the list of alphabet in the perluniprop?*

`\p{IsAlpha}` is indeed defined in [perluniprops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html). [Note the correct spelling.] It defines

```
\p{Is_*}          ⇒   \p{*}
\p{Alpha}         ⇒   \p{XPosixAlpha}
\p{XPosixAlpha}   ⇒   \p{Alphabetic=Y}

\p{Alpha: *}      ⇒   \p{Alphabetic=*}
\p{Alphabetic}    ⇒   \p{Alphabetic=Y}
```

so `\p{IsAlpha}` is an alias for `\p{Alphabetic=Y}`<sup>[1]</sup>. Unicode defines what characters are Alphabetic<sup>[2]</sup>. There are quite a few:

```
$ unichars '\p{Alpha}' | wc -l
10391
```

So back to the question. `$pre =~ /\p{IsAlpha}/` checks if *any* of the characters in the string in `$pre` is an alphabetic character.

> *One related question is whether the fullstop is already inside the perluniprop alphabet?*

No.

```
$ perl -e'CORE::say "." =~ /\p{IsAlpha}/ ? "match" : "no match"'
no match

$ uniprops .
U+002E <.> \N{FULL STOP}
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Basic_Latin Punct Is_Punctuation Case_Ignorable CI Common Zyyy Po P
       Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph X_POSIX_Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax
       PatSyn POSIX_Graph POSIX_Print POSIX_Punct Print X_POSIX_Print Punctuation STerm Term
       Terminal_Punctuation Unicode X_POSIX_Punct
```

In contrast,

```
$ uniprops a
U+0061 <a> \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A}
    \w \pL \p{LC} \p{L_} \p{L&} \p{Ll}
    AHex POSIX_XDigit All Alnum X_POSIX_Alnum Alpha X_POSIX_Alpha Alphabetic Any ASCII
       ASCII_Hex_Digit Assigned Basic_Latin ID_Continue Is_IDC Cased Cased_Letter LC
       Changes_When_Casemapped CWCM Changes_When_Titlecased CWT Changes_When_Uppercased CWU Ll L
       Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph X_POSIX_Graph GrBase Hex X_POSIX_XDigit Hex_Digit IDC ID_Start
       IDS Letter L_ Latin Latn Lowercase_Letter Lower X_POSIX_Lower Lowercase PerlWord POSIX_Word
       POSIX_Alnum POSIX_Alpha POSIX_Graph POSIX_Lower POSIX_Print Print X_POSIX_Print Unicode Word
       X_POSIX_Word XDigit XID_Continue XIDC XID_Start XIDS
```

> *If so, wouldn't this condition never be true?*

```
$ perl -E'CORE::say /\./ && /\p{IsAlpha}/ ? "match" : "no match" for $ARGV[0]' a
no match

$ perl -E'CORE::say /\./ && /\p{IsAlpha}/ ? "match" : "no match" for $ARGV[0]' .
no match

$ perl -E'CORE::say /\./ && /\p{IsAlpha}/ ? "match" : "no match" for $ARGV[0]' a.
match
```

---

1. Underscores and spaces are ignored, so `\p{IsAlpha}`, `\p{Is_Alpha}` and `\p{I s_A l p_h_a}` are all equivalent.
2. The list of alphabetic characters is slightly different than the list of letter characters.

   ```
   $ unichars '\p{Letter}' | wc -l
   9540

   $ unichars '\p{Alpha}' | wc -l
   10391
   ```

   All letters are alphabetic, but so are some alphabetic marks, roman numerals, etc.

Comment: You can use `perl -E'say "hello"'` instead of `CORE::say`.

Comment: `-E` isn't forward compatible. I don't want the code to be affected by a Perl upgrade.