# Perl Grep command to search in array

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I am using Perl and grep command to look for pattern in an array output.
I am interested in searching for the following text in an array:

```
/tmp/12345.hash
```

The `12345` could be any sequence of numbers like `234` or `567889` but the `/tmp/` and the `.hash` will be consistent.  I am not great with regex therefore not sure how to build the proper regex statement.

```
@line = grep /hash/, @exp;
```

My original search was to look just the word hash but that matched on other lines and i ended up with the wrong result.

Answer (score 4):

Regex allows you to encode requirements into a "pattern" with a lot more precision:

```
my @filtered = grep { m{^/tmp/[0-9]+\.hash$} } @all;
```

I use `{}` for delimiters since with the usual `//` ones every `/` in the pattern must be escaped. Then `m` is required in front (unlike with `//` delimiters where it may be omitted).

The anchor `^` matches the beginning of the string (and at yet other positions if the `/m` "modifier" is in effect)<sup>†</sup>.  The `/tmp` seems to be the beginning of a path, but if there were (for example) leading spaces before it then the above wouldn't match (unless you change it to `^\s*/tmp` so to allow for optional spaces). Consider your data carefully.

The `$` matches the end of the string, or before the newline at the end if there is one (`/m` modifier changes this)<sup>†</sup>. To also match strings with more characters after `hash` remove the `$`.

The pattern itself sets down what you say in the problem description: there must be an integer, which varies, and the rest is fixed.

Perl's own (excellent) documentation comes with the tutorial [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

---

<sup>†</sup>  With the modifier, `$str =~ /.../m`, the string is treated as a multi-line string so that if there are linefeeds in it then `^` and `$` in that regex match the beginning and end of each line as well.

The anchor to always match only the end of the string is `\z` (also see `\Z` which matches like `$` but is insensitive to `/m`).  See [Assertions in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Assertions), and see answers on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32526929/4653379).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response...I am testing it now..I noticed the missing closing } but looks like you fixed it.  Thank you for the explanation, very helpful.

Comment: @user3521305 Ah, yes, there was a typo (or a couple?) in what I initially posted -- have fixed them, and edited more.  Let me know if things are unclear.

Comment: `\z` matches the end of the string. `$` matches more than the end of the string.

Comment: hum? You're still using `$`, and you still claim it matches the end of the string. Even without `/m`, `$` doesn't just match the end of the string.   `$` is equivalent to `(?=\n\z)|\z` without `/m`, and it's it's equivalent to `(?=\n)|\z`) with `/m`.

Comment: @ikegami OK, you mean that it matches _before_ the newline if there is one at the end (like `\Z`) so not at the end. Thank you again. (It's interesting that this is _never_ distinguished, except in docs.)